# Preg_replace not behaving as I expected

Tags: php, preg-replace

I have what I thought would be a simple preg_replace however is causing me a few issues.

Input
`Thank you $(-1) for raiding us! Go follow him guys! twitch.tv/[1]`

Replacement
`preg_replace("/\[(\d+)\]/", "\$(${1})", $output);`

Expected Output
`Thank you $(-1) for raiding us! Go follow him guys! twitch.tv/$(1)`

The purpose of this is to move from an old API to a new one - The [1] could be at any position in the input string

The Problem I'm having is that this is outputting
`Thank you $(-1) for raiding us! Go follow him guys! twitch.tv/$()`
And seems to be ignoring the capture group

EDIT:
Solved by changing the Replacement to
`preg_replace('#\[(\d+)\]#', '\$(${1})', $output);`

Comment: Are u sure? Seems to work [perfect](http://ideone.com/qLdRPy)

Comment: I'm positive. I've tried several variations of formatting and I just can't get it to output the digit from the capture group. It works perfectly here too: http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/8BE  
The full script so far can be found at: http://pastebin.com/hWvR6qfb
as I guess it could be something i'm doing wrong here

EDIT: Nevermind I just checked your example and it works.. I seemed to be missing the "#"s. Please answer with your example and I'll mark as complete :) (not that I understand what the '#'s are for :P

Comment: The `#` are just [delimeters](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php), it marks the start and the end of your RegEx. A delimiter can be any non-alphanumeric, non-backslash, non-whitespace character, I just prefer `#`, most people tend to use `/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost got it right. This does the job for me:

```
$output = 'Thank you $(-1) for raiding us! Go follow him guys! twitch.tv/[1]';
$new_output = preg_replace("/\[(\d+)\]/", "\$($1)", $output);

print($new_output."\n");
```

With the curly brackets you can insert a PHP-variable and seperate it from replacement text like this

```
$php_var = 'replacement';
$output = 'Thank you $(-1) for raiding us! Go follow him guys! twitch.tv/[1]';
$new_output = preg_replace("/\[(\d+)\]/", "\$(${php_var}_and_then_some)", $output);

print($new_output."\n");
```

Comment: Ahh this makes sense! 
There are so many modifiers in preg_replace usage I guess I got lost in my brackets and curly brackets :D

Thank you for your help! :)